# SK61 Skyloong Optical hotswappable keyboard random switch on the board doesn't work (right shift)

Tags: keyboard

So I figured this out typing along and when pressing the switch it actually won't even let me type a different key. It's an sk61 from skyloong and it's a premade keyboard. So I hadn't touched the internals before this at all and it has never got water damage. I just opened it there to check if it was the switch (optical gateron browns) but I tried another switch that worked fine where it was and nope. So it's not the switch any ideas as to what I can try other than send this thing back for a new one?

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed my issue while typing the question mark on the end of the question xD I pressed it and it worked with that but not with any of the letter keys. I needed to run the drivers for the lights and shit and it worked fine again. I don't know if I should leave this up or not I will take it down if anyone asks :)